# C++ Callback on thread end and result returning

Tags: c++, multithreading

How can I accomplish this scenario purely asynchronously:
Let's assume there is one thread working asynchronously which creates new thread when some conditions were fullfiled:

```
class listener {  
    ...
    void on_message(data_type data) {  
        if(some_specific_data_found(data)) {  
            do_some_work_in_new_thread(new_thread, data, callback_on_end);
        }
    }
    ...
    void callback_on_end(result_type result) {
        do_some_work_in_this_thread(result);
    }
    ...
}
```

Newly created thread looks like this:

```
void new_thread(data_type data) {  
    auto result = do_some_work_here();
    push_result(result); // This result should be accessible in 
                         // callback_on_end function.
}
```

I know that I can achieve similar solution using futures, but I don't want to call any blocking function like `get()` or `wait()`.

Comment: Do you want something like [future::then](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future/then) ?

Comment: [std::future::wait_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) doesn't block. Is that unusable for your needs?

Comment: Store your results in a thread safe structure which you can poll against.

Comment: Then you have to store the result in a thread safe data structure and in main thread check the data structure periodicity for new results.

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42 - that's the solution. Admittedly, I didn't use experimental implementation of future::then from STL, but I used one from Boost.

Comment: you can use my library, concurrencpp: https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp . it supports `future::then` and also `co_await`. header only without the boost mess.

Answer (score 0):

mutex::lock / unlock
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex
you can unlock it when the first thread returns.

Answer (score 0):

I used `boost::future::then` like this:

```
    boost::future f =
        boost::async(boost::launch::async, // start task in new thread
                     boost::bind(task_code, task_args));  

    boost::future end_callback = f.then([&](auto i) {
        auto result = i.get(); // i is of type future; get() returns object
                               // of type result_type_of_task_code
                               // get() is nonblocking
        do_something(result);
    });
```